# Can we use java to design specflows?

Tags: automated-testing, java, cucumber, tdd, specflow

I am currently learning regarding specflows to design acceptance testing using cucumber, But I am getting information that we can not use java or Java script programming language only .net is supported so just would like to understand is that limitation correct ?
Is there any workaround regarding same?

Answer (score 3):

Use [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/). Specflow is a part of cucumber family that is developed for .Net world. So if you do not need .Net but need Java, just use the solution that was originally intended for Java